# Consigo rodar programa feito em Delphi 6 em versões mais atuais de Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Consigo rodar um programa feito em Delphi 6 em versões mais recentes?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 4):

Em tese sim, mas pode depender do código específico. Há algumas pequenas coisas que se tornaram incompatíveis, então só tentando para saber. Mesmo que alguma coisa não funcione é bem simples adaptar para funcionar.

Obviamente que não terá acesso aos recursos novos automaticamente. Alguma manutenção pode se tornar mais complicada. Se estiver usando componentes externos de terceiros pode ser bem mais complicado.

Comment: Exato, efetuamos a migração de um sistema aqui da empresa, mais de 1400 units... Saímos do Delphi 5 diretamente para o XE8, muito trabalho mas é possível sim!

Comment: Vale lembrar que para inicio, você deve Re-declarar as uses, nas versões antigas o Delphi usa apenas "Forms" no padrão novo é "Vcl.Forms" é interessante você migrar e já começar seguindo a nova tendência! Pois, hoje não apenas a VCL, tem a FMX também.

Comment: Acredito que os obstáculos principais são os componentes de 3º e Unicode.

Comment: Boas observações dos comentários.